# connect opscenter and datastax agent runs in two docker containers

Tags: ssh, docker, cassandra, datastax

There two containers which is running in two  physical machines.One container for Ops-center and other is for (datastax Cassandra + Ops-center agent).I have have manually installed Ops-center agent on each Cassandra containers.This setup is working fine.
But Ops-center can not upgrade nodes due to fail ssh connections to nodes. Is there any way create ssh connection between those two containers. ??

Comment: do you want to upgrade the Ops-center agent *inside* the container? Best practice with Docker is to not do that, but to consider containers "immutable", and replace the container with a new one that has an updated version of the software inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

In Docker you should NOT run SSH, read [HERE](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/) why. After reading that and you still want to run SSH you can, but it is not the same as running it on Linux/Unix. This article has several options.

If you still want to SSH into your container read [THIS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/) and follow the instructions. It will install OpenSSH. You then configure it and generate a SSH key that you will copy/paste into the Datastax Opscenter Agent upgrade dialog box when prompted for security credentials.

Lastly, upgrading the Agent is as simple as moving the latest Agent JAR or the version of the Agent JAR you want to run into the Datastax-agent Bin directory. You can do that manually and redeploy your container much simpler than using SSH.

Hope that helps,
Pat